# Jekyll: Group some collections but not all

Tags: jekyll

I need to group some of the collections so that I can password protect that group.  At the same time I want to keep the `_posts` collection open, so it needs to remain at the root of jekyll.

For example, this is group `secure`

```
collection:
  notes:
    output: true
  hybrid: 
    output: true
collections_dir: secure
```

How can I exclude the collections such as `_posts` and also custom ones being grouped under `secure`?

Can I use permalinks to achieve this?  For example

```
collection:
  notes:
    output: true
    permalink: /secure/:path/
  hybrid:
    output: true
    permalink: /secure/:path/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  The permalinks option is in fact best in this situation.  That way `_posts` remains at the root of jekyll and other collections which do not need to be grouped are also behaving normally.

Once you build the site, all grouped collections will be under `_site/secure/` locally and will be under `http://example.com/secure/` on your server.  Make sure to set up http authentication using `htpasswd`.  There is plenty of material on the web on how to do this.

Comment: Yes, and then add an htaccess file to the secure directory of the build. Is that what you have done? Maybe you can elaborate on the htaccess part.

Comment: I use nginx which does not support `.htaccess` files, but I added a note to my answer about authentication.